# Problema al guardar datos en arreglo con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo este código jquery:

```
var preguntas_examen = [];
var preguntas_contestadas = [];
var cont = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
    obtenerPreguntas(function(data){
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            preguntas_examen.push(data[i]);
        }
        
        imprimirPregunta();
    });
    
    $(".btn-form").on("click", function(){
        getRespuestaAlumno();
        
        if(cont < preguntas_examen.length)
        {
            if(revisarContestacion())
                imprimirPregunta();
            else
                Swal.fire('Atención', 'Por favor selecciona una respuesta', 'warning');
        }
        else
        {
            $(".panel-title").html("Total de preguntas contestadas: " + cont);
            $(".panel-body").empty();
            Swal.fire('¡FELICITACIONES!', 'Has terminado de contestar tu examen', 'success');
        }
    });
});

function getRespuestaAlumno()
{
    if($("input[name=optionsExamen]").length >= 1)
    {
        $("input[name=optionsExamen]").each(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked"))
            {
                var respuesta = {
                    "id_pregunta" : $(this).parent(0).parent(0).parent(0).children("#id_preguntaVal").val(),
                    "respuesta" : $(this).val(),
                    "correcto" : $(this).parent(0).parent(0).parent(0).children("#correctoVal").val(),
                    "archivo" : 0
                }
                
                preguntas_contestadas.push(respuesta);
                
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        if($("input[type=file]").length >= 1)
        {
            subirArchivo(function(data){
                var respuesta = {}
                
                if(data != null)
                {
                    respuesta = {
                      "id_pregunta" : $("#uploadArchivo").parent(0).parent(0).children("#id_preguntaVal").val(),
                      "respuesta" : $("#uploadArchivo").parent(0).parent(0).children("#respuestaVal").val(),
                      "archivo" : data
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Swal.fire('Atención', 'No se pudo enviar el archivo', 'warning');
                    
                    respuesta = {
                      "id_pregunta" : $("#uploadArchivo").parent(0).parent(0).children("#id_preguntaVal").val(),
                      "respuesta" : $("#uploadArchivo").parent(0).parent(0).children("#respuestaVal").val(),
                      "archivo" : ""
                    }
                }
                
                preguntas_contestadas.push(respuesta);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            var respuesta = {
                "id_pregunta" : $("#respuestaVal").parent(0).children("#id_preguntaVal").val(),
                "respuesta" : $("#respuestaVal").val()
            }
            
            preguntas_contestadas.push(respuesta);
        }
    }
}

function revisarContestacion()
{
    var contesto = false;
    
    if($("input[name=optionsExamen]").length >= 1)
    {
        $("input[name=optionsExamen]").each(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked"))
            {
                contesto = true;
                
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    else
        contesto = true;
    
    return contesto;
}

function imprimirPregunta()
{   
    $(".panel-title").html("Pregunta: " + (cont + 1));
    $(".p-pregunta").html(preguntas_examen[cont]["pregunta"]);
    
    if(preguntas_examen[cont]["tipo"] == 1)
    {
        var inputPregunta = $("<div class='radio'><label><input type='radio' name='optionsExamen'"
          + "value='" + preguntas_examen[cont]["respuesta1"] + "'>" + preguntas_examen[cont]["respuesta1"]
          + "</label></div><div class='radio'><label><input type='radio' name='optionsExamen'"
          + "value='" + preguntas_examen[cont]["respuesta2"] + "'>" + preguntas_examen[cont]["respuesta2"]
          + "</label></div><div class='radio'><label><input type='radio' name='optionsExamen'"
          + "value='" + preguntas_examen[cont]["respuesta3"] + "'>" + preguntas_examen[cont]["respuesta3"]
          + "</label></div><input type='hidden' id='id_preguntaVal' value='" + preguntas_examen[cont]["id_pregunta"] + "'>"
          + "<input type='hidden' id='correctoVal' value='" + preguntas_examen[cont]["correcto"] + "'>");
        
        $(".form-group").html(inputPregunta);       
    }
    else if(preguntas_examen[cont]["tipo"] == 2)
    {
        var inputPregunta = $("<div class='radio'><label><input type='radio' name='optionsExamen'"
          + "value='" + preguntas_examen[cont]["respuesta1"] + "'>" + preguntas_examen[cont]["respuesta1"]
          + "</label></div><div class='radio'><label><input type='radio' name='optionsExamen'"
          + "value='" + preguntas_examen[cont]["respuesta2"] + "'>" + preguntas_examen[cont]["respuesta2"]
          + "</label></div><input type='hidden' id='id_preguntaVal' value='" + preguntas_examen[cont]["id_pregunta"] + "'>"
          + "<input type='hidden' id='correctoVal' value='" + preguntas_examen[cont]["correcto"] + "'>");
        
        $(".form-group").html(inputPregunta);
    }
    else if(preguntas_examen[cont]["tipo"] == 3)
    {
        var inputPregunta = "";
        
        if(preguntas_examen[cont]["archivo"] == 1)
        {
            inputPregunta = $("<textarea class='form-control' id='respuestaVal' rows='3'></textarea><span><input type='file' id='uploadArchivo'></span>"
              + "<label for='uploadArchivo'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-file'></span> Seleccionar archivo</label>"
              + "<input type='hidden' id='id_preguntaVal' value='" + preguntas_examen[cont]["id_pregunta"] + "'>");
        }
        else
        {
            inputPregunta = $("<textarea class='form-control' id='respuestaVal' rows='3'></textarea>"
              + "<input type='hidden' id='id_preguntaVal' value='" + preguntas_examen[cont]["id_pregunta"] + "'>");
        }
        
        $(".form-group").html(inputPregunta);
        
        if(preguntas_examen[cont]["archivo"] == 1)
        {
            $(':file').change(function(){
              var filename = jQuery(this).val().split('\\').pop();
              $('label[for=uploadArchivo]').html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-file'></span> " + filename);
            });
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var inputPregunta = "";
        
        if(preguntas_examen[cont]["respuesta3"] != "")
        {
            inputPregunta = $("<div class='radio'><label><input type='radio' name='optionsExamen'"
             + "value='" + preguntas_examen[cont]["respuesta1"] + "'>" + preguntas_examen[cont]["respuesta1"]
             + "</label></div><div class='radio'><label><input type='radio' name='optionsExamen'"
             + "value='" + preguntas_examen[cont]["respuesta2"] + "'>" + preguntas_examen[cont]["respuesta2"]
             + "</label></div><div class='radio'><label><input type='radio' name='optionsExamen'"
             + "value='" + preguntas_examen[cont]["respuesta3"] + "'>" + preguntas_examen[cont]["respuesta3"]
             + "</label></div><input type='hidden' id='id_preguntaVal' value='" + preguntas_examen[cont]["id_pregunta"] + "'>"
             + "<input type='hidden' id='correctoVal' value='" + preguntas_examen[cont]["correcto"] + "'>");
        }
        else if(preguntas_examen[cont]["respuesta2"] != "")
        {
            inputPregunta = $("<div class='radio'><label><input type='radio' name='optionsExamen'"
             + "value='" + preguntas_examen[cont]["respuesta1"] + "'>" + preguntas_examen[cont]["respuesta1"]
             + "</label></div><div class='radio'><label><input type='radio' name='optionsExamen'"
             + "value='" + preguntas_examen[cont]["respuesta2"] + "'>" + preguntas_examen[cont]["respuesta2"]
             + "</label></div><input type='hidden' id='id_preguntaVal' value='" + preguntas_examen[cont]["id_pregunta"] + "'>"
             + "<input type='hidden' id='correctoVal' value='" + preguntas_examen[cont]["correcto"] + "'>");
        }
        else
        {
            if(preguntas_examen[cont]["archivo"] == 1)
            {
               inputPregunta = $("<textarea class='form-control' id='respuestaVal' rows='3'></textarea><span><input type='file' id='uploadArchivo'></span>"
                + "<label for='uploadArchivo'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-file'></span> Seleccionar archivo</label>"
                + "<input type='hidden' id='id_preguntaVal' value='" + preguntas_examen[cont]["id_pregunta"] + "'>");
            }
            else
            {
               inputPregunta = $("<textarea class='form-control' id='respuestaVal' rows='3'></textarea>"
                + "<input type='hidden' id='id_preguntaVal' value='" + preguntas_examen[cont]["id_pregunta"] + "'>");
            }
        }
        
        $(".form-group").html(inputPregunta);
        
        if(preguntas_examen[cont]["archivo"] != "undefined" && preguntas_examen[cont]["archivo"] == 1)
        {
            $(':file').change(function(){
              var filename = jQuery(this).val().split('\\').pop();
              $('label[for=uploadArchivo]').html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-file'></span> " + filename);
            });
        }
    }
    
    cont++;
}
```

Estoy haciendo una pagina para contestar examenes online, el problema es cuando hay inputs tipo `file`, no guarda los valores de los inputs `hidden` que se generan, pone valores undefinidos, por que hace lo quiere y no me hace lo que estoy pidiendo?

Comment: Indica en qué parte del código exactamente ocurre el problema.

Comment: @A.Cedano no se en que parte del código ocurre el problema porque el explorador no marca nada

Comment: Aquí estás describiendo el problema: *el problema es cuando hay inputs tipo file, no guarda los valores de los inputs hidden que se generan, pone valores undefinidos*. Se supone que eso ocurre en alguna parte del código, ¿en qué parte ocurre? Si no sabes dónde es, entonces depura el código mediante `console.log` hasta encontrar donde falla. Es que tal y como está planteada la pregunta nos obligas a examinar todo el código, luego a intentar descrifrar su lógica para entonces encontrar el problema. Se requiere de tu parte un mínimo esfuerzo de depuración.

Comment: @A.Cedano y como quieres que encuentre el error si te estoy diciendo que no marca nada en la consola

Comment: De plano nadie va ayudar, pues que a todo dar no??